# Do page table entries at each level in a Two-Level Paging system have to be the same size?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, multi-level

Let's say hypothetically you have a two-level paging system with a 32-bit logical address and the page offset has been predetermined to be 12-bits. This leaves 20-bits for the page numbers. All the examples I can find online and in textbooks show the page numbers then split into 2 blocks of 10 such that the virtual address looks something like this:

[ p1: 10-bits | p2: 10-bits | offset: 12-bits ]

Do both page numbers have to be 10-bits? For example, can it be this instead:

[ p1: 8-bits | p2: 12-bits | offset: 12-bits ]

And what about using an odd number of bits for the page numbers, such as:

[ p1: 9-bits | p2: 11-bits | offset: 12-bits ]

I understand splitting them evenly, makes everything clean and orderly. I'm just trying to figure out what it is technically possible and if there are any drawbacks/benefits to doing it differently.

---

**Full Disclosure: This question itself is not a homework problem, but a question that arose while trying to solve a homework problem. Not trying to get anyone to do my work for me. Just trying to understand what is possible and if there are any advantages/disadvantages of doing it one way or the other.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason that they need to be the same size other than to simplify the implementation.  In fact, in some systems (such as x86), the `p2` field you show can be part of the `offset` for some pages and not others, to allow multiple page sizes.

Comment: Okay thanks.  I figured that was probably the case, but couldn't find any examples showing otherwise. Just wanted to make sure I didn't try to solve a problem under a false premise.